# Awaiting a coroutine and assigning the result to a variable outside of a coroutine

Tags: python, import, async-await, discord.py, asyncpg

I would like to be able to make a utils file that I can call on that's using a list of commands all requesting data from a database:

```
import asyncpg

async def is_registered(ctx):
    pg_con = await asyncpg.create_pool(database="Db", user="postgres", password=db_pw)
    registered = await pg_con.execute("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE user_id = $1)", ctx.author.id)
    if registered:
        await ctx.send("hi")
        return True
    else:
        return False

async def is_registered(ctx): #another function
    pg_con = await asyncpg.create_pool(database="Db", user="postgres", password=db_pw)
    registered = await pg_con.execute("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE user_id = $1)", ctx.author.id)
    if registered:
        await ctx.send("hi")
        return True
    else:
        return False

...
```

and so on. I would like to call these functions in another file using `import`. Are there any downsides of naming `pg_con` every time, and is there a way to handle it so I don't have to? And are there better ways to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in using a connection pool to execute a single query, and it would be a lot slower establishing a connection/pool each time.

The better way to handle this would be to subclass [`Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot) and add the connection pool as an attribute.
That way, there's a single pool that you can access through [`Context.bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.bot).

Also, note, in your example, you're shadowing the function.

Comment: However, I would need to access subclass Bot from my utils folder which does not derive from it, in order to call on it. How would I do that?

Comment: If you use the subclass in place of `Bot`, you can access it through `Context.bot` like I said, since you're passing a `Context` object to the function in your example.